# How Can I Convert Between A Solidity Timestamp And Year/Month/Day Hour:Minute:Second?

Tags: solidity, timestamp, datetime

Solidity provides the `uint256` **`now`** or **`block.timestamp`** [Special Variable](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html#special-variables-and-functions).

How can I convert between this Solidity timestamp and *year*/*month*/*day* *hour*:*minute*:*second*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Warning - Self Promotion**

There are a few libraries that provide the functionality to perform the conversions between the timestamp and *year*/*month*/*day* *hour*:*minute*:*second* including:

- @piper-merriam 's [Ethereum Date and Time tools](https://github.com/pipermerriam/ethereum-datetime)
- [SkeletonCodeworks](https://github.com/SkeletonCodeworks)'s [Date utilities for Solidity contracts](https://github.com/SkeletonCodeworks/DateUtils)

And now there is @bokkypoobah's [Gas-Efficient Solidity DateTime Library](https://github.com/bokkypoobah/BokkyPooBahsDateTimeLibrary). More information about it in this [medium post](https://medium.com/@BokkyPooBah/bokkypoobahs-gas-efficient-solidity-datetime-library-92bf96d9b2da).

Comment: Nice contribution, but should probably add *self promoting*...